# custom linear scales in D3

Tags: d3.js

I have a linear scale and I am using it for one of my axis in a chart.

I want to define a custom format only showing positive numbers and following [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176) example I created a customFormat in this way:

```
    function yFormat(formats) {
        return function(value) {
            var i = formats.length - 1, f = formats[i];
            while (!f[1](value)) f = formats[--i];
            return f[0](value);
        };
    }

    var customFormat = yFormat([
        [d3.format("?????"), function() { return true }],
        [d3.format("d"), function(d) { return d >= 0 }]
    ]);
```

but I don't know how to define an `empty` format for Numbers ([link to doc](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting))

Does anybody have an idea? Thanks

**EDIT**

`d3.format("")` seems to work for time scales but not for linear scale. In a console:

```
> var emptyTime = d3.time.format("");
  undefined
> emptyTime("something");
  ""
> var emptyInt = d3.format("");
  undefined
> emptyInt(5);
  "5"
```

**ANSWER**

I am just using tickValues on the axis itself. So, something like:

```
yAxis.tickValues(
            d3.range(
                0,
                d3.max(y.domain()),
                shift
            )
        );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "empty" format? `d3.format("")`?

Comment: I tried that but it shows the negative numbers, for some reason..

Comment: It does the job if the scale is a time scale, but it does not seem to work with linear scales.

Comment: You would have to set the ticks to be shown explicitly using `tickValues` in this case. The formatter is really only that.

Comment: Ok, so the scale will contain negative values but ticks are only shown for positive ones. Nice thanks!